# Change toolbar config to latest CKEditor toolbar groups

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

There is a ckeditor plugin that I really want to use (Line Height), but after looking at its `.js` file I can see that it is configured to work with the ckeditor `config.toolbarGroups` concepts, which configures the toolbar like so:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
];
};
```

However, I use the ckeditor module, with a drupal 7 codebase, and after I install the plugin and its dependencies, the button for the lineheight plugin doesn't show up when I go to `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/**{text format}**`.

Is there a way to edit the **lineheight** plugin code so that it works with the **ckeditor** module?

```
editor.ui.addRichCombo( comboName, {
        label: editor.lang.lineheight.title,
        title: editor.lang.lineheight.title,
        toolbar: 'styles,' + order,
        allowedContent: style,
        requiredContent: style,
        panel: {
            css: [ CKEDITOR.skin.getPath( 'editor' ) ].concat(   config.contentsCss ),
            multiSelect: false,
            attributes: { 'aria-label': editor.lang.lineheight.title }
```

Or, is there a way to convert the **ckeditor** module to from using the method below to using the new method above?

```
// Toolbar definition for all buttons
Drupal.settings.cke_toolbar_DrupalFull = [
['Source'],
['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','SpellChecker',   'Scayt'],
['Undo','Redo','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll'], 
  ['Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','Iframe'],

'/',
['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript','- ','RemoveFormat'],
['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote','CreateDiv'],
['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl','-','Language'],
['Link','Unlink','Anchor','Linkit','LinkToNode', 'LinkToMenu'],
'/',
['Format','Font','FontSize'],
['TextColor','BGColor'],
['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks'],
['DrupalBreak', 'DrupalPageBreak']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the dev version of the [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)module, you'll be able to use the latest CKEditor ***library*** with all the fancy plugins.

Comment: I was hoping not to use the wysiwyg module, but looks like there now way around it.  Its seems rather "backwards" that the folks that maintain ckeditor module, wouldn't actually update the ckeditor module to match their latest release of ckeditor... I am sure its in the pipeline, just not right now...  thanks for the answer...